# If a video is removed from a site like YouTube or Dailymotion, is it removed from blog posts too?

Tags: youtube, tumblr, video, wordpress

For example, say you have a Tumblr or WordPress blog with a video from YouTube on it, if that video is removed from YouTube for some reason, can it still be accessed through your blog?

I would think if it's just a link it could not be accessed but I don't know if there is some way to actually move the video content itself to your blog to avoid this from happening.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is removed from the blog post as well. These videos are *embedded* in your blog so there is a direct link to anything that happens on the hosting site.

The video will appear to still be viewable on your site, but the moment you click play you should see otherwise.

To keep it on your site, you will need to host the video yourself.